# Auth0 authentication with angular 4 requires double log in

Tags: angular, auth0

I have built an app using Angular 4 and Auth0 authentication. Everything works well but when I log in, quite often (though not always) I am forced to log in twice. The first time it fails because the nonce does not match.

This error does not occur in development but only in production. I am hosting using the Google Cloud Platform. Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Sounds similar to [this issue](https://github.com/auth0/auth0.js/issues/429), can you try the given workaround?

Comment: The workaround here refers to renewing the auth. That is not the case here. I am just using new auth0.webauth...

Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue? Sometimes experience this, as well.